Installing third party software (HSL) in Ipopt/pyomo
I recently obtained the academic version of solvers from the HSL website and need to configure IPOPT to switch between solvers (e.g., from MUMPS to MA57) in the options.
Could someone guide me through the steps to configure this on Windows?

There are installation steps described at https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html
There are prebuild HSL libraries available at https://licences.stfc.ac.uk/products/Software/HSL/LibHSL. If Ipopt has been build such that it can load HSL solvers at runtime (which is the default), then it should be sufficient to set Ipopt options linear_solver and hsllib (https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html).
